# I lose state in my BloC when I navigate routes and then come back. Why?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have this code. In summary, I am learning Flutter and I created this code just to practice. The goal is to type in a TextField and then press a FloatingActionBotton and onPressed it updates a text widget. I used BloC as a state manager. Then, just to test Flutter behavior, I created a new screen to go back and forth and see it works. I was surprise to see that I lost my state in my home page and that I can't even update the text widget anymore after pressing the FloatingActionButton. What happened?

When I come back to home screen, the text widget is gone and when I press the floatingactionbutton (add icon) I get an exception BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a ExampleBloc.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: BlocProvider.value(
      value: ExampleBloc(),
      child: Home(),
    ),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late TextEditingController teste;
  late String lol;

  @override
  void initState() {
    teste = TextEditingController();
    lol = 'ola';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: teste,
          ),
          Center(child: BlocBuilder<ExampleBloc, ExampleState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Text(state.exampleString ?? 'null');
            },
          ))
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              lol = teste.text;
              BlocProvider.of<ExampleBloc>(context)
                  .add(ExampleUseEvent(exampleString: lol));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HEHE()),
            ),
            child: Text('next screen'),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Text('pop'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    teste.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class HEHE extends StatelessWidget {
  const HEHE({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(child: Text('teste')),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                  ),
              child: Text('next screen')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {
  ExampleBloc() : super(ExampleState()) {
    on<ExampleUseEvent>(exampleFuncion);
  }

  Future<void> exampleFuncion(
    ExampleUseEvent event,
    Emitter<ExampleState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      exampleString: event.exampleString,
    ));
  }
}

abstract class ExampleEvent {}

class ExampleUseEvent extends ExampleEvent {
  final String exampleString;

  ExampleUseEvent({required this.exampleString});
}

class ExampleState extends Equatable {
  final String? exampleString;

  ExampleState({
    this.exampleString,
  });

  ExampleState copyWith({
    String? exampleString,
  }) {
    return ExampleState(
      exampleString: exampleString ?? this.exampleString,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        exampleString,
      ];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the state bloc plis?

Comment: initially i used state in my bloc to test but then i noticed i could simplify my bloc by using String. but now i guess String cant hold state and thats why i am losing state?

Comment: i just edited the post. the full code all together so its easier to test/understand

Answer (score 1):

Example bloc only exists in fist page when it is provided by MaterialApp.

Switch MaterialApp and BlocProvider.value to get the desired result.

MaterialApp contains Navigator which contains list of PageRoutes when pages are pushed. If BlocProvider will be defined before MaterialApp, it will be available to all the pages.

Comment: you got it right! now it works! i just put BlocProvider before MaterialApp and it now works. can you explain the logic behind it? why does it work like that? i dont understand honestly

Comment: What we define in flutter code is app's widget tree. There is a root widget at top and it has some children. All of these children can access its parent or ancestor. Now if you take each child and make it root of subtree and recurse, you get widget tree. This is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look how I use bloc in Flutter, I think your error is because you don't have a state of your bloc, so, the data reset.

example_state.dart

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class ExampleState extends Equatable {
  final String? exampleString;
  
  ExampleState ({
    this.exampleString,
  });
  
   ExampleState copyWith({
    String? exampleString,
  }){
    return ExampleState(
      exampleString: exampleString?? this.exampleString,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
    exampleString,
  ];
}
```

example_bloc.dart

```
class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {

  ExampleBloc() : super(ExampleState()) {
    on<ExampleUseEvent>(exampleFuncion);
  }

  Future<void> exampleFuncion(
    ExampleUseEvent event,
    Emitter<ExampleState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      exampleString: event.exampleString,
    ));
  }
}
```

example_event.dart

```
abstract class ExampleEvent {}

class ExampleUseEvent extends ExampleEvent {
  final String exampleString;

  ExampleUseEvent({required this.exampleString});
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work. initially it works just as expected. but if i navigate to screen HEHE and then comeback again to screen Home then the Text dissapears and when i try to write in the TextField again and press the floatingbotton to send the event to the bloc and populate the Text widget i get an exception "Each child must be laid out exactly once." and this "BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a ExampleBloc."

Comment: hey again. i have just edited the post so the code is all together. its easier to copy and test it to see what i mean. i have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Dont forget the BlocProvider in the main file